# Viewing component relations in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, components

Is there a way to see component relations in android studio? I am hoping for some kind of graph or tree of how components relate to each other: such as which activity calls which activity, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to see component relations in android studio?

Not at this time, sorry. Even if this is added, it will have holes, just as similar tools for mapping method calls break down when reflection is used.